# memcpy structure variables

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, memcpy

It might sound a very basic question but I have following structure in C++:

```
struct SMessage
{
    unsigned int id; 
    unsigned int payloadSize; 
    unsigned char data[100];  
    unsigned char *data2; 
};
```

lets say I have two variables of SMessage type (msg1,msg2) and i want to memcpy individual members of msg1 into msg2 (please dont ask why!). I understand that copying id and payLoadSize are relatively straight forward:

```
memcpy(&msg2.id, &msg1.id, sizeof(unsigned int)); 
memcpy(&msg2.payLoadSize, &msg2.payLoadSize, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

but for copying the data[] should we do:

```
memcpy(&msg2.data, &msg1.data, 100*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

or

```
memcpy(msg2.data, msg2.data, 100*sizeof(unsigned int))
```

would also work because data is an array object?

How will we copy the struct member data2 which is declared as a pointer instead?

Comment: Reminder:  the `memcpy` will copy the *pointer* `data2`, **not** the data that `data2` is pointing to.

Comment: Why don't you just use `sizeof msg2.data` to determine the size? That said, `msg2 = msg1` would also work to copy the structure. Further, using `memcpy()` to copy anything is wrong in most cases, so consider not using it at all! E.g. for the fixed-size arrays, you should use C++ `std::array` which allows simple assignments. Even without that, using `std::copy` would be much cleaner and safer.

Comment: I agree with using `std::copy`. It probably uses `memcpy` internally in your implementation, and the abstraction will help you prevent mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either version would work.  Using the ampersand (&) operator explicitly takes the address of the array, while omitting the ampersand causes it to implicitly take the address of the array.  In the end, the result is the same.

More importantly, it is easier and less error-prone to use sizeof directly on the field:

```
std::memcpy(msg2.data, msg1.data, sizeof(msg1.data));
```

That avoids typos and, more importantly, if the field changes size you don't have to go through your code finding places you've used it.

As for data2, zwol, in his answer below, is correct in that it depends on what exactly data2 is storing -- or, more accurately, who "owns" data2 and how the variable will be freed.  You might want to look into "shallow" versus "deep" copying.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the expression `msg.data` is different from the type of the expression `&msg.data`, but the *values* are identical.  Since this is C++, the behavior is very clearly specified in `[conv.ptr]/2`: the call to `memcpy` causes an implicit conversion of both pointer arguments to `[const] void *`, and the result of this conversion "points to the start of the storage location where the object resides, as if it is a most derived object (not a base class subobject)".  (In C, the effect is the same, but the standardese is less clear about saying so — you have to read C99 section 6.3.2.3 paragraphs 1 and 7 together and understand that `memcpy` behaves "as if" it converts its arguments to pointers-to-character-type internally.)

`data` is declared as

```
unsigned char data[100];
```

therefore all of the following are equivalent and correct.  The first of them would be the preferred style in most codebases I've worked on.

```
memcpy(msg2.data, msg1.data,   sizeof msg1.data);

memcpy(msg2.data, msg1.data,   100);
memcpy(msg2.data, msg1.data,   100 * sizeof(unsigned char));

memcpy(&msg2.data, &msg1.data, sizeof msg1.data);
memcpy(&msg2.data, &msg1.data, 100);
memcpy(&msg2.data, &msg1.data, 100 * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

However,

```
memcpy(msg2.data, msg1.data, 100 * sizeof(unsigned int));
```

is WRONG; it copies too much memory.¹  This is why the form with `sizeof` is preferred style; it is harder to get wrong in the first place, and does not silently become wrong if the type definition is changed.²

Also as a matter of style, I prefer not writing an `&` in this context, because `&[anything with an array type]` is almost always wrong, so it should not be written that way unless it's actually necessary.

And you should know that `sizeof(any sort of char) == 1` **by definition** (C++ [expr.sizeof]/1).  It is my personal, but widely shared, opinion that this means `sizeof(char)` should never appear in your code.

Finally, I can't tell you the correct way to copy `data2` without more information.  I need to know what `data2` points to, how it is allocated, and whether it should be copied or referenced.

---

¹ except in the very unlikely case that `sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(unsigned int)`; this was true on the original Cray, and the standards still allow for the possibility, but AFAIK no implementor has actually done that in many, many years.

² Counterargument: this is applying `sizeof` to an array type, which is risky, because array types "decay" to pointer types if given the slightest opportunity to do so, so again it would be silently wrong.  In the case you're in, though — copying structure members by hand — I think it's less dangerous than the alternative.

Comment: You don't have to cast a pointer to void*; you need a cast to convert from void*.

Comment: @Steven My memory of the standard says you're mistaken about that, but I don't have it on this computer so I can't check.

Comment: It looks like it's section 4.10.2, at least of the current working draft at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf: A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
to cv void”.

Comment: @Steven I need to confirm that it said that or the equivalent in C++98 before I can change the answer, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your last two `memcpy()`s should be `sizeof(msg1.data)` not `100*sizeof(unsigned int)` - they're `unsigned char`s anyway!

But the last one:

```
memcpy(msg2.data, msg2.data, 100*sizeof(unsigned int));
```

is correct. If you want to use the earlier one, use:

```
memcpy(&msg2.data[0], &msg1.data[0], 100*sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are wrong because they will cause out-of-range access if `sizeof(unsigned int)` is larger than `sizeof(char)`.

You can do either one of

```
memcpy(&msg2.data, &msg1.data, sizeof(msg1.data)); // pass pointers to arrays
memcpy(msg2.data, msg1.data, 100*sizeof(unsigned char)); // pass pointers to first elements of the arrays
```